# Passing in a Task to to make a method more generic for reuse does not behave as expected asynchronously

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, async-await, task

So essentially I want to pass in an Action or Function Lambda statement to a method to reuse a generic timer functionality with different methods.  So I could do something like GenericTimer(1000, Task1DoesThisThing) and GenericTimer(3000, Task2DoesThisCompletelyOtherThing).  I just want reusability and do not care if a different method is given to me drastically different than what I am doing.

```
private static void TimerGeneric(int duration, Task timerDuration)
{
  var timer = new Timer(duration);
  timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await timerDuration;
  timer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void TimerSetupWithRefresh(int refreshDuration)
{
  Timer timer = new Timer(refreshDuration);
  timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await Refresh();
  timer.Enabled = true;
}

private static async Task Refresh()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Specific is: " + DateTime.Now);
}

public class Poc { public int Id { get; set; } public string Value { get; set; }}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //Works just as expected and refreshes every second for the 'Refresh()' method.
  TimerSetupWithRefresh(1000);

  //Below does not work yet I would expect a Task passed in via signature with near same method would behave the same.
  TimerGeneric(1000, new Task(() => { Console.WriteLine("Passed in Task is: " + DateTime.Now); }));

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing in a `Task` which is never started. I think what you actually want is to take a delegate which invokes an asynchronous method, this can be done using a parameter of type `Func<Task>` like so:

```
private static void TimerGeneric(int duration, Func<Task> timerDuration)
{
    var timer = new Timer(duration);
    timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await timerDuration();
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
TimerGeneric(1000, async () => { Console.WriteLine("Passed in Task is: " + DateTime.Now); });
```

Although it would be preferential for the async method to actually perform some asynchronous work, or failing that simply return a completed `Task`:

```
TimerGeneric(1000, () => 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Passed in Task is: " + DateTime.Now);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```

This can be preferential as it eliminates the underlying asynchronous state machine which is unnecessary for a synchronous implementation.

Comment: That is what I needed.  I thought I was doing something simple wrong in my signature pattern.  Thanks